# How can I use adb to change Android TV picture settings?

Tags: android, adb, android-tv

I recently bought a Hisense A6G Android TV and to my dismay the settings UI doesn't provide an option to disable Motion Enhancement aka Motion Smoothing aka "the soap opera effect". So I started poking around to see if I can change it using adb.

I found a setting that sounds like exactly what I want to change:

$ dumpsys settings | grep motion_enhancement

_id:66591 name:tv_picture_advance_picture_motion_enhancement pkg:com.android.tv.settings value:3 default:3 defaultSystemSet:true

I can get and set this value using the settings command, but it's not having an immediate effect on video playback:

$ settings put global tv_picture_advance_picture_motion_enhancement 0

$ dumpsys settings | grep motion_enhancement

_id:66627 name:tv_picture_advance_picture_motion_enhancement pkg:com.android.shell value:0 default:3 defaultSystemSet:true

At the very least I probably need to restart some process to read in this new value, and I wouldn't be surprised if it's more complicated than that.

A possibly relevant side note: I found the setting volume_music_speaker returns the actual volume of the TV, but changing that setting doesn't change the actual volume of the TV. After more searching, I found this command does change the actual volume, optionally showing the volume indicator on the TV:

$ media volume --stream 3 --set 42 --show

I wonder if there is a similar command for changing picture settings.

Any suggestions for what to try next?

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar for backlight level. Did you ever make any progress?

Comment: I'm sad to say I gave up. I wasn't getting anywhere with trial and error, and I haven't been able to find any useful documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but I wanted to let @Andrew Noblet know that at least on my Hitachi, the following command works!

> settings put global picture_backlight 5

(this is 5 percent)